# How to destroy a session only when user closes/leaves all the pages of the website in php?

Tags: php

I have 5 pages in my website , page1.php , page2.php, page3.php ,page4.php, logout.php.

page4.php has a login form and above it has a php script to catch the user input from the login form and put it in a session, and then redirect user to the page of my site where he came from (by using header('location: '.$_SESSION['page']);) , or if he didn't come from any pages , i.e his first visited page is page4.php then redirect him to page1.php. and top most has session_start();

Page1.php , page2.php and page3.php code:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['page'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
 // also have a link to click to go to page4.php if not logged in and a link to   
 //logout.php
?>
```

code of logout.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('location: '.$_SESSION['page']);
?>
```

Problem is when user clicks logout link logout.php destroying all session and redirecting to the page where it came from which again sets $_SESSION['page'] and not getting destroyed even all pages are closed. So next time if user first visits page4.php and login he is being redirecting to the page last time he was in when he visited the site.I want if user closes all pages(if he had multiple tabs of site pages opened) and then first visit to the page4.php , he will be redirected to page1.php.
  how do i destroy session only if all the pages of the site are closed?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
session_start();
$temp = $_SESSION['page'];
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
header('location: '. $temp);

?>
```

If I understand you right you want the session data to be cleared so it won't use old pages after logout.

PHP.net example on how to end a session correctly:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php#example-4515

Comment: Even he logs out he still wants to stay in the site without loggin in and that is why $_SESSION['page'] is still needed, if he again wants to relog , so that after relogging he will be redirected to that page. so i want to destroy the session if and only if user closes all pages/tabs of the site

Comment: @user1906399: Then why are you destroying the session in the first place?

Comment: That cant be done with just PHP as it has no way of knowing if tabs are still open to other pages. What you can do is use AJAX to ping the server every so many seconds with the page name, then when logging out you can see when the last ping was, if no ping has occurred after the scheduled ping interval you can be fairly sure no tabs are still open.

Comment: Btw if a user chooses to logout he expects to be logged out and not have other tabs keep him logged in. That would make logging out pointless then. Just my thoughts. If you want to keep pages after logout then set a cookie so it doesn't rely on session.

Comment: @hakre: suppose i am in page3.php , i liked the page , so i want to log in so i clicked the login link , which takes me to page4.php where the login form is , and after login there i am being redirected back to page3.php.Now i logout.Next day i am back to the website , but i first opened the form page , i.e page4.php , to login , now after login it is taking me again to page3.php.i want if i come atfirst via form page i want to be redirected to page1.php not to page3.php.That is why i need to destroy the session.

Comment: Well if you *need* to destroy the session, by definition you can't keep `page` from the session. Now you are lost ;)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it make sense to first destroy all sessions when the user logs in to the site first before setting any new sessions? The same goes for each new page loaded as long as you don't need anything from the previous page. Obviously you will need your log in session, so you will not destroy that session.

Comment: While destroying existing sessions upon login is a valid strategy, that's not going to help the OP I'm afraid: he needs to figure out how to destroy the session(s) properly.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use `session_unset()` to clear all `$_SESSION`. For a specific `$_SESSION` variable, use `unset($_SESSION['whatever'])`

Comment: [`session_unset`](http://php.net/session_unset) does nothing in modern PHP.  It acts only on [registered session variables](http://php.net/session_register), an obsolete feature that should never be used in modern code.